# Adding numbers containing commas in a batch script

Tags: scripting, batch-file, dos, number-formatting

I'm trying to add two numbers together in a windows batch file.  The numbers are coming from the output of a command and I cannot change the code to output it in a different format.

The problem is that the numbers use commas in the numbers as the thousands separator.  i.e. `154022` is output as `154,022`.  Now when I try to add this number to another number it only adds the first part (i.e. that `154`).

```
set A=1,000
set B=154,022

set /a TOTAL=A + B

echo %TOTAL%
```

produces: `155`, not `155022` that I would like, or even `155,022` would do.

Is there a way to convert easily from numbers with commas to numbers without commas in a batch script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set A=1,000
set B=154,022

set A2=%A:,=%
set B2=%B:,=%

set /a TOTAL=A2 + B2

echo %TOTAL%
```

You can do string manipulation like this

```
set result=%input:substring=replacement%
```

---

This one and other nice tips: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: You beat me to it, now take that! :) (+1)

Comment: thanks Tomalak that worked :).  I have since decided that batch scripting in general is god awful and am reverting to doing this job in PHP!

Comment: @fwgx Yes, batch scripting under Windows is a pain in the ass. ;-)